# Unable to instantiate MongoDB Document class with Map containing Any values

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongodb-java

Been recently trying to compress within a single `Map` all the values that will go within my `$set` clause when performing an upsert to MongoDB.

However, this was previously done with a single typed `Map[String, Long]` which worked. However, since I know that `$set` may contain (and does) different types I wanted to put in there multiple fields that I do need in the `$set` clause.

I've tried the following without any success.

```
                  "$set" -> Document(
                    item.getAs[Map[String, _]]("mapField")
                  )
```

This complains already in the IDE with `Cannot resolve overloaded method Document`.

Is there any way to accomplish this without using the `++` operator and thus having more columsn spread accross the DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

Scala `Map` is not the same as a Java `Map` and you forgot about `new` word before `Document`. `Document` constructor expects Java map but you tries to pass the scala map. I think you need to convert scala map to java map:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
"$set" -> new Document(
  mapAsJavaMap(item.getAs[Map[String, Object]]("mapField"))
)
```

Comment: No luck either, with a Java approach still expects a BsonDocument and not a Map.

Comment: @czr_RR where it expects a BsonDocument please write class name? Witch mongodb driver are you using?